# My Rest Api Does Not Run With Ionic-2

Tags: node.js, heroku, ionic2

I have made a rest api for my ionic-2 android app but my http request cannot get data from my rest api service
I made a rest api with node.js and source code here

> server.js

```
 var express = require("express");
 var app = express();
 var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended:true
 }));

 app.use(bodyParser.json());

 var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
 var router = express.Router();

 router.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.json({
        "message":"hello world"
       });
 });

 app.use('/api',router);

 app.listen(port);

 console.log("Listening Port");
```

> package.json

```
{
"name": "node-api",
"main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.0.0",
    "mongoose": "~3.6.13",
    "body-parser": "~1.0.1"
  }
}
```

I pushed on heroku service and its address here
[my heroku rest api link](https://appish.herokuapp.com/api)

My  ionic2 app from another directory here

> home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';  
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
   data:any;
   constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,http:Http) {

  http.get("https://appish.herokuapp.com/api")
     .map((res) =>res.json())
     .subscribe((data)=>{
     this.data = JSON.stringify(data);
   })
  }
 }
```

> home.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
     Api
    </ion-title>
 </ion-navbar>
```

```
<ion-content padding>
    {{data}}
</ion-content>
```

When I run this code with 'ionic serve' there is no error and no data but if I try other json sites to get data,it is running for example
i am trying [ip.jsontest.com](http://ip.jsontest.com/)
I can get data
Where is the problem

Thank You 
~

Comment: Try adding an error handle to the http.get request. you can add a .catch(function(error: Response | any) { console.log(error) }) and see if there is output from there.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a CORS issue.

Try adding this to the beginning of your server.js and see if it resolves your issue.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

If that doesn't work, you should take a look at the network tab in your browsers debugging tool. If you get a response and can see the data, it is an error in your ionic code. If you don't get any data, it's a problem with your server code or with the connection to the server.

Answer (score 0):

> Replaced server.js

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
   extended:true
}));
//answer is here..
app.use(function(req,res,next){
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
next();
});
///
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/',function(req,res){
        res.json({
         "message":"hello world"
        });
 });

 app.use('/api',router);

 app.listen(port);

 console.log("Listening Port");
```